# Transients in Java

Tags: java, syntax

I was looking at JOptionPane.java. On line 387 there is

```
transient protected Object
```

and on line 399 there is

```
protected transient Object
```

.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None. Just poor coding standards. On your code try to use the 2nd one.

Answer (score 5):

The second one follows the code conversion, the first one doesn't.  They are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

No difference.  This order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

According to the JLS, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1

> 8.3.1 Field Modifiers
>
> ```
> FieldModifiers:
>   FieldModifier
>   FieldModifiers FieldModifier
>
> FieldModifier: one of
>   Annotation public protected private
>   static final transient volatile
> ```
>
> If two or more (distinct) field
>   modifiers appear in a field
>   declaration, it is customary, though
>   not required, that they appear in the
>   order consistent with that shown above
>   in the production for FieldModifier.

So it would appear the second one is more conventional.

Answer (score 2):

No, the order of these keywords does not matter. See this [article on the transient keyword](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient) for more information.